# Angular can i read more parameters from html like <base href="/folder">?

Tags: angular

My API url is not the same, so I want to pass in the HTML a varibale like `<base href="/another-folder">`.
For example something like `<apiurl href='/my.api.url'>`

Can i read `apiurl` from angular if the above exist?
What would be the proposed way to pass the url of the api through HTML ?

Comment: Do you actually have to declare that in the HTML? you can use an `environment` variable to hold the endpoint and then import it in in your services (or create a base class that imports this and then your services extends that base class)

Comment: It has to be in HTML yes, because the same app will be distributed among different websites, so i dont control their environment settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how trustable is this, but this is the only thing I can think of. First, if you want to read data from your document, you need to inject the `DOCUMENT` in your component/service. Second, you need a place to declare this data somewhere in the `<head>`. For this you can use `data-*` attributes. So in your `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head data-endpoint="/my.api.url">
    <!-- head stuff -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

As I said before, if you want to extract this value from within Angular, let's say from a service, we have to get a reference of the document, so your service could look like this:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class ApiEndpointService {
  endpoint: string;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _doc: Document) {
    this.endpoint = this._doc.head.dataset.endpoint;
  }

  getEndpoint(): string {
    return this.endpoint;
  }

}
```

Where `dataset` gives you access to `DOMStringMap` object, that is a key value pair where keys are the `*` in whatever `data-*` attribute you defined, and value the actual value of the attribute.

I don't really know if this is malpractice or if it's totally fine, but be careful if you're trying Server Side Rendering since I don't know if accessing the document will work in that scenario.

Comment: I'll try it out and get back to you. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: It works pefect. Dont worry i'm not setting anymore than the alias of the subdomain. He can see it anyway from the network.